# Why This Code Gives Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault

Below code snippet is run on linux, and it reports Segmentation Fault (Core Dump). I found error happens when the destructor is called, but can't figure out why. Can anybody help explain this?

```
    class TStringPair{
    public:
        TStringPair(){
            memset(this, 0, sizeof(TStringPair));
        }


        string a;
        string b;
    };

    int main (int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        TStringPair test;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: C++ == don't use memset

Comment: By default, a class is initialized with its default values, which is 0 in most cases. Useing memset destroys any non 0 values that should have been there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `memset` ruins your class quite literally. The memory of a `std::string` (as well as many other C++ classes) should not be filled with zeros, but you fill both.

To illustrate why this is a bad idea, consider a `std::string` having a pointer to the actual characters. Oops, instead of pointing to a null string, it now points to 0. There are other reasons why zeroing out a non-C object is bad, but they aren't quite as relevant to this example.

I imagine removing the `memset` and putting nothing in its place would give the exact result you were going for.

Comment: Beat me by literally 7 seconds.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, Well, I realized during my second expansion to my comment that it was probably better as an answer :p

Comment: Of course, on most platforms a NULL pointer is made up of zero-bytes... so there's probably more to it than that.  Your point stands, though; memset()-ing the memory of a non-POD C++ object is a no-no.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, Well, at the very least, barring optimizations, it would cause a memory leak because the pointer to allocated memory is lost.

Answer (score 2):

Just before the body of your TStringPair constructor runs, the std::string class's default constructor gets called (automatically) for each of your two string member-objects.

The std::string default constructor sets the contents of those two objects to their correct state.  What is that correct state?  We don't know (not without looking through the STL source code, anyway), but that's okay, because we don't have to know -- we can rely on the std::string class implementers to do the right thing.

However, after those constructors run, your memset goes through and overwrites (whatever info they wrote) with zero-bytes... now those string objects are in a corrupted state, so it's no surprise that you get a crash when their destructor runs and encounters that corruption.